# jQuery code somehow moves all elements together, why?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, dom

I bumped into this code:[Foursquare like feed](http://motyar.blogspot.co.il/2010/09/foursquarecom-like-animated-feeds.html) here's the working [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ilikuh)

but I can't figure out why it makes all the feeds ("#feed0", "#feed1","#feed2" ...) altogether??

Ironically... Why does this code work? :)

There is some part that erases the feed when it comes to its end, I don't know why. It looks pretty standard but I am not a jQuery expert. 
I did notice the animations complete right on the spot.
The `shift()` function happens right away and the animation happen just after it completes.

1. What makes the bunch of divs move together?
2. what is needed to make it operate on n number of feeds?

Comment: by "moving together" you mean sliding down together? that's because they are block layouted divs, if one grows bigger, it pushes the other ones down.

Comment: Beautiful! But do you know why the feeds disappear at the end?

Comment: because the parent container is fixed size and has an `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

1. Sections move together because in the html they're inside a div block.
2. In the code, under `JavScript(Jquery)`, if you look at the 3rd line, it says:

   var showing = 3; //How much items to show at a time

This is why it disappears at the end. If you increase the number, it'll show more.